# Properly launching an iOS app into the background from a location event

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

(iOS 11, Swift 4.1)

I wrote a cordova plugin in swift to handle region monitoring, but it isn't working properly when my app is suspended or killed. Here is my class with the relevant functions:

```
class GeofenceManager : NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didDetermineState state: CLRegionState, for region: CLRegion) {
      switch state {
          case .inside:
              log ("Did Enter Region: " + region.identifier)
              self.postGeofenceTransition(region: region, transitionType: 1)
              break
          case .unknown:
              log ("Unknown Transition for region: " + region.identifier)
              // self.postGeofenceTransition(region: region, transitionType: 1)
              break
          default:
              break
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
        log ("Did Exit Region: " + region.identifier)
        self.postGeofenceTransition(region: region, transitionType: 2)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didStartMonitoringFor region: CLRegion) {
        log("Did start monitoring region: " + region.identifier)
        self.locationManager.requestState(for: region)
    }
}
```

(I do it this way to handle someone that's already in the region when we start monitoring)

I've also got "didChangeAuthorizationStatus" that fetches and sets all the geofences, that is working fine.

In my AppDelegate (objc) I'm attempting to start Location Services if the app is opened from a region event, with

```
if([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey]) {
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [_locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [_locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLHeadingFilterNone];
    //change the desired accuracy to kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    [_locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    //SOLUTION: set setPausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically to NO
    [_locationManager setPausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically:NO];
    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

My question is, if my app is opened from an event, i.e. "didEnterRegion", I immediately start location services, but will I hit my "didEnterRegion" delegate again? And am I doing something wildly wrong here?

I think I'm missing some understanding of iOS application states, have dug into the docs but it hasn't clicked yet. Any insight is very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, if my app is opened from an event, i.e. "didEnterRegion", I immediately start location services, but will I hit my "didEnterRegion" delegate again?

If your app was suspended or terminated, and if it is awakened or launched just to receive `didEnterRegion`, it stays *in the background*. It is given time just to handle this one event and then it is suspended.

You cannot start location updates with `startUpdatingLocation` at that point. You are in the background! Even if you are authorized for background updates, you cannot *start* getting updates while you are in the background. And even if you could, *your* code would fail, because you never set `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates`. And even if you could do *that*, you wouldn't get any events, because you have no implementation of `didUpdateLocation`.

The correct procedure is: do nothing. Just handle `didEnterRegion` and get out. If the user enters the region again, your `didEnterRegion` will be called again. Region monitoring just goes on forever until you stop it (and make sure you *do* stop it, or the user may be be forced to delete your app).

**Addendum**: How to respond to being launched from scratch in the background like this? You can detect the key in `didFinishLaunchWithOptions` and handle it there and return `false`, or you can ignore it and return `true` and receive `didEnterRegion`. But either way you must immediately create a location manager and appoint its delegate or you will get nothing, obviously. This is why you should *always* create the location manager and set its delegate in your app delegate or root view controller, something that *always* exists, and exists as *early* as possible in the life of the app, as soon as it launches.

Comment: Thank you for the help, this clears up a lot of my confusion. Does it matter where my `didEnterRegion` delegate is implemented? I was under the impression that if the app is launched from this event, I land in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` with my `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey` set. This would leave me to believe I need to create an instance of `CLLocationManager` in `AppDelegate` and implement `didEnterRegion` there, then as you mentioned, get out/stop region monitoring as appropriate.

Comment: Ah. Okay, you've got two choices. You can detect the key in `didFinishLaunchWithOptions` and handle it there and return `false`, or you can ignore it and return `true` and receive `didEnterRegion`. But either way you must immediately create a location manager and appoint its delegate or you will get nothing, obviously. This is why you should _always_ create the location manager and set its delegate in your app delegate or root view controller, something that _always_ exists, and exists as _early_ as possible in the life of the app, as soon as it launches.

Comment: Awesome, will take another look at which way I'd like to do it and give one a shot. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, added that last comment into my answer, as it is not at all obvious.